Word press wp-admin redirecting to reauth=1
We've hosted word press on AWS EC2 instance, and it's attached to AWS application load balancer(Internet facing), then it's attached to AWS cloud front, our website is pointing to AWS cloud front.
Requests follows this: User --> www.example.in --> AWS cloud front --> AWS ALB --> AWS EC2 instance.
When we are trying to access the word press with Domain name it's able to load,
Since WP application is hosted on httpd under /var/www/html/blogs/ so when we are trying to access the webpage www.example.in/blogs/ its loading but web pages is breaking I mean to say page structure is not good.
the issues is here When we're trying to access the wp-admin page www.example.in/blogs/wp-admin it's redirecting https://www.example.com/blogs/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fnvirginia-xxxxx-app-lb-2030706760.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com%2Fblogs%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
Followed multiple solutions but nothing working for me.
.htaccess file for redirection
[root@ip-10-0-2-194 blogs]# cat .htaccess
# BEGIN WordPress Multisite
# Using subfolder network type: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/htaccess/#multisite

# Let apache know we're behind a SSL reverse proxy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on

# Redirect to HTTPS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /blogs/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . /blogs/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress Multisite

[root@ip-10-0-2-194 blogs]# 

added this lines inside wp-config.php.
/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );

define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.in/blogs');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.example.in/blogs');

/* Turn HTTPS 'on' if HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO matches 'https' */
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}

/** Handle real IP address */
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ips = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = trim($ips[0]);
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) {
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

even we've updated our db with siteurl and home.
MariaDB [wordpress]> SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' OR option_name = 'home';
+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| option_name | option_value                      |
+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| home        | https://www.example.in/blogs |
| siteurl     | https://www.example.in/blogs |
+-------------+-----------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [wordpress]> 

we've created the certificate with *.example.in www.example.in and attached it to on the AWS cloud front and application load balancer also.
Our end goals is that we want to access the wp-admin page from our domain.
When we hit the www.example.in/blogs/wp-admin we need to get the login page and able to login.
I'm Very new to Word press, if you fell that given .htaccess and wp-config.php are wrong. please do let me know what i need to modify to make it work, Thanks in advance.

With AWS you may also be having permissions issues - I have encountered that before to the point that I stopped using AWS because I could never get it working properly.
Depending on how things are added to the site, the install done via AWS or FTP but then the theme uploaded through WordPress means that they get tagged with different sets of permissions and thus files stubbornly refuse to work together.

Installed the word press on AWS ec2 instance, we've provided required permission on the word press files and folders.
